# Adding pictures to the shapefile objects in QGIS/QField?

Tags: qgis-2.18, qfield

Here is the thing, I want to add pictures that either are georefered (BY GPS Camera) or added manually to both new created objects and existing objects.

Now to be clear I do not mean adding pictures to the map canvas itself, but the objects themselfs. I want know how to do this both in QGIS (by adding local images from a computer) and Qfield (by taking a picture from the Smartphone/tablet camera which is then georefered.

I have made an illustration about what is going to happen, this is actually bigger than the questions itself. Because I am gonna ask some other question compared to this. **What I ask in this questions is marked in orange.**

[image]

**How do I do this?**

Comment: When talking about "objects", you mean features? You want to import a picture (with geotag) as a feature( I assume point geometry) with an attribute that stores the file path to the image, with the picture being copied into a specific directory on the local system? If so, you are porbably looking for a pyqgis solution :) .

Comment: Uhm kind of. What I want in simplier terms is that a picture gets added to a point object/feature when it gets created. The picture is still linked to the shapefile and the object tied to that picture. Sometimes the picture has a geotag (In case with Qfield) and something it does not have geotag (a local pc file).

Comment: Basically you want to automate a tedious task, then: You create the features manually, then want to simply reference a picture (second input). The image is copied&stored in a predefined folder, and the reference path to that image is stored as an attribute of the feature. If correct, that is very likely a pyqgis question.

Comment: Any starting guides about pygis and how to set this script I am new to this.

Comment: A good starting point is the [official PyQgis cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/), and you'll find plenty of help here on GIS.SE under the pyqgis tag. Your script will require a mix of regular Python and pyqgis, but overall it's a great starter project. I'd recommend approaching this as a pyqgis processing script. That's a fairly intuitive self-teaching approach to pyqgis. If you want/need more pointers, just keep asking!

Comment: Did you solve this @ThunderSpark? I had something similar here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287339/how-to-enable-camera-and-take-pictures-for-features-in-qfield?rq=1. Adding pictures to vector features works fine in Qfield. Only downside is that I don't know how or if it is possible to upload said pictures to a server automatically. So far they only get saved on device's hard drive.

Geotags one could just enable from device's settings. Though, I don't know how to edit CRS in which it is done. 

If you had a different solution in the end, consider posting it as an answer?