# How to enable camera and take pictures for features in QFIELD?

Tags: qfield

My question is as in the title. I'm struggling to find a way, *how I could add a camera function in QFIELD in order to take pictures of features in field*. I've seen one similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236718/adding-pictures-to-the-shapefile-objects-in-qgis-qfield), but it's been left unanswered for more than a year now. As far as I know, this functionality does exist somehow.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you seen the link at http://www.qfield.org/docs/index.html pointing to https://vimeo.com/173774749?

Comment: No, I haven't. In the video digitizing mode is on when picture is added. Is it possible to add a picture to an existing feature? Thanks!

Comment: To answer my own question above: yes it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out finally. Thanks to Matthias Kuhn for assistance.

First one needs to create an attribute form ("Attachment", used to be "External resource") for a layer field in question. This will enable camera function once in Qfield. Open properties-dialog of your layer to accomplish this.

[image: Attribute form-tab in properties dialog]

Once you're working with Qfield, be thoughtful about saved paths of taken pictures: you have to choose between file paths and directory paths. In case you transfer manually your pictures from your mobile device to PC, your directories will change thus I myself chose to save file paths.

What I didn't yet find out was, how to save pictures directly to a server.

Comment: i look your solution but if you need update a object the picture is not possible, the attachment file its solution for new objetcs but for old objects take pictures is not possible? if the old objetc have picture its possible update but if dont have picture is not possible take one. Its a bug??